# Repeating an animation sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a bunch of code here -- http://jsfiddle.net/gDX3d/

A nice guy helped me the other day with this.  What I want it to do is continue to loop, rather than stop at the end.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the below else part inside `mouseOutProps` `complete` method. This will restart the animation from beginning.

```
else{
    queueOne($('.caption').first());
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gDX3d/1/)**